# ui-grid - command to undo all column changes?

Tags: angularjs, ui-grid

I can make all sorts of column changes in the browser to a grid made with ui-grid - move columns around, hide columns, set various sorts, etc.  But I don't see a command I can use, add or access (presumably to/from the grid menu) to undo all the changes I made at once.  I can reset the page or log out, but then I lose the data from my search.

Does such a command exist?

Comment: Did you check the docs? http://ui-grid.info/docs/#!/api

Comment: I have, but not quite knowing what to look for has hampered my success. There's a command refreshRows() which is listed as not functional, and I can't tell if the other commands with refresh in them are the right ones for my needs. As mentioned, I'm looking only to reset the column display, not refresh/delete the data.